# Performing conditional linear interpolation in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, interpolation

My if else statement is not performing correctly.

The following code is an example dataset, data1_df is the table in which I want to use for linear interpolation to get the interpolated value based on its location and data2_df is my actual dataset which includes account level information for location and score.

```
data1 = {'Central' : [10, 20, 50],
         'Greater London' : [15, 40, 50],
         'Rest of Uk' : [5, 14, 20],
         'Value' : [5, 4, 3]}

data2 = {'Account' : [1, 2, 3],
         'Location' : ['Central', 'Greater London', 'Rest of Uk'],
         'Score' : [25, 45, 18]}

data1_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(data1_df)
print(data2_df)
```

The corresponding score in data2_df are used to calculate the linear interpolated score in data1_df based on its Location. I have created an if else condition based on the code below. However, my results (new column Value Interpolated) don't seem to be correct and it appears that regardless of the condition, it performs the interp_rest_uk interpolation for all Locations (including Central and Greater London).

```
for index, row in data2_df.iterrows():
    Location = row['Location']

if Location == 'Central':
    interp_central_london = interp1d(data1_df['Central'], data1_df['Value'], kind='linear',fill_value='extrapolate') 
    value_interp = data2_df['Score']
    score_interp = interp_central_london(value_interp)
    data2_df['Value Interpolated'] = score_interp
    
elif Location == 'Greater London':
    interp_greater_london = interp1d(data1_df['Greater London'], data1_df['Value'], kind='linear',fill_value='extrapolate') 
    value_interp = data2_df['Score']
    score_interp = interp_greater_london(value_interp)
    data2_df['Value Interpolated'] = score_interp
    
else:
    interp_rest_uk = interp1d(data1_df['Rest of Uk'], data1_df['Value'], kind='linear',fill_value='extrapolate') 
    value_interp = data2_df['Score']
    score_interp = interp_rest_uk(value_interp)
    data2_df['Value Interpolated'] = score_interp

print(data2_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted your code correctly into the StackOverflow question, then it appears that the indentation of your `if-elif-else` block is off. Basically, your code runs over all the items in `data2_df`, and only then starts looking at the interpolation. So the location will always be that of the last item in `data2_df`, which happens to be `Rest of UK`.

Comment: i have made changes so there is an indendation of the if-elif-else block, however, I am still getting the same results in that it only picks up the Rest of UK condition.